# How do I fix this "Accessed None trying to read property Save Game" error?

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

I have create this blueprint, with a Check for an existing Save-Game and load it in case of true. Else, create a new save game object. While Z is pressed, create a new Save Game, getting the Player Position.

The problem is that when I try to start the game, I have two errors:
[image]

How can I solve those problems? This is my blueprint:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to a StackExchange site! Although you have specified an error in the title, it is always a good idea to write as text in the core of the question the errors you get, instead of pasting screenshots of the errors (although the screenshots do not harm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your problem is very simple - in the beginning, you haven't connected return value of "does save game exist" node to the branch. Fix that and see if it works :)

Comment: Thank you very much! +1

Comment: You're welcome :)